# Select values from one column and display in two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm stumped trying to figure out a way to display data from one column in two different columns. The data is a bill of materials in Oracle, and I want to display certain items in the bill of materials in a second column.

For example, I have a master item which is 123ABC. Within this item it has the following items ... AA1, BB1, CC1. They all belong to the same column in the same table.

I'm trying to get a query to to display two columns, the first column would be master item, and the second column would be sub item that shows all items beginning with 'AA' like below...

```
Master Item  |  Sub Item
-------------------------
123ABC       |  AA1
```

So far I have the following...

```
 select distinct msi.item FNUMBER
 ,       msi.description DESCRIPTION
 , (select msi1.item
 FROM inv.mtl_sys_item msi1 
 WHERE msi1.item = msi.item)
 from
 ,      .mtl_sys_item  msi
 where msi.segment1 = '123ABC'   
 order by 1 desc
```

But this just displays the master item 'ABC123' in both columns instead of the AA1 in the second column.

Comment: can you share the table structure of mtl_sys_item and representative data for the column where you are trying to extract the data from

Comment: Are using the scalar because there are many matches in the `mtl_sys_item` table and you only want to return one?  So are you discarding BB1 and BB2, or do you expect them to display in subsequent rows?

Comment: mtl_sys_item  has 4 columns... organization_id, inventory_item_id,  item & description.

Comment: And what data allows to define that some record X is sub-item for some record Y (and/or backward)?

Answer (score 0):

Your data must have some sort of parent item column. You can use this to do a self-join:

```
SELECT msi.item as FNUMBER,
       msi.description as DESCRIPTION,
       msic.item
FROM inv.mtl_sys_item msi JOIN
     inv.mtl_sys_item msic
     ON msi.item = msic.parent_item  -- guessing at the column name
WHERE msi.segment1 = '123ABC'   
ORDER BY 1 desc
```